# DAX 2009 Enterprise Portal: Passing Different Contexts to Different Pages

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, microsoft-dynamics, ax, enterprise-portal

I have a page that shows a grid of Customer Contracts (KeyField = ContractId), and when I click on the **ContractID**, it takes me to the **Contract Detail** page with the proper Contract details displayed.  On THAT page, I would like to be able to click on a referenced Sales Order to see the **Sales Order Detail** page for the specific **Sales Order** that was clicked.

If I use a regular **AxBoundField** to display the **SalesId**, the page renders properly, but if it's an **AxHyperLinkField**, it won't render.  It feels like an incorrectly set property, but I can't put my finger on it.

I've made sure to add the necessary SalesID field to the contract dataset object, but when I setup the **AxHyperLinkField** with the **SalesID**, the page no longer renders. The AxHyperLinkField is pointing to the correct WebMenuItem (SalesOrderDetail - a pre-existing menu item), but I'm having difficulty figuring out why the page won't render.